# bioconductor: satuRn Error message interpretation

Tags: r, dataframe, bioconductor

I am using satuRn to run an experiment on Rstudio, and I am getting an warning message that I don't know how to fix. I tried looking up resources but I could not find anything useful.
Could anyone decode how to fix this warning?

**satuRn Command line**

```
sumExp <- satuRn::testDTU(
  object = sumExp,
  contrasts = L,
  #plot = FALSE,
  sort = TRUE
)
```

**Warning**

```
Warning: f(z) misfit = 1.6.  Rerun with increased df
```

I'll really appreciate any insight. Thank you

Comment: Bioconductor has [it's own support site](https://support.bioconductor.org) and all package creators commit to supporting their packages on that site, so you should absolutely make use of it and tag `saturn`. Also, please be more careful with terminology: a "Warning" is not an "Error".

Comment: thank you ! I will read through the support site